# Как обнаружить станции в ЛВС с открытым портом?

Tags: tcp-ip, port

Как в локальной сети обнаружить все станции, на которых открыт N-й TCP-порт?

Поясню. В сети есть мастер и множество устройств, которые могут начать взаимодействие с мастером. Классический пример - сетевая компьютерная игра. Мастер создаёт игру, а ведомые запускают поиск игры. Как они осуществляют поиск?

С ходу придумал следующие кривые решения:

1. Сканирование всего адресного диапазона. Не подходит из-за того, что сеть класса В.
2. Периодическая отправка кадра с широковещательным MAC-адресом (как мастером, так и ведомым). Способ рабочий, но неправильный с точки зрения инкапсуляции. Стандартная библиотека большинства языков программирования предоставляет доступ только к TCP и UDP-сокетам, а с их помощью можно работать лишь с транспортным уровнем. Для работы с канальным уровнем нужен драйвер WinPcap.

Какие будут идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете отправить UDP пакет на широковещательный IP-адрес, а мастер (сервер) на него ответить.

Answer (score 2):

Есть же классическое решение - zeroconf - [статья на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/66020/).

Суть - сервер по udp рассылает инфу о сервисе, все желающие могут ее оттуда вычитать. Есть пользовательские поля, куда можно дописать немного своей информации.

Comment: >Сервер по udp рассылает инфу о сервисе
Вы имеете в виду широковещательную рассылку? @mantigatos тоже предлагает использовать широковещательный ip-адрес, но разве они не запрещены? Насколько мне известно, широковещательные ip-адреса использовались для атак и поэтому были запрещены около 5 лет назад. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Я предлагаю не просто широковещательный адрес, а готовый инструмент. Если бы то, о чем я пишу, было запрещено, то очень много вещей в этом мире не работало (к примеру, поиск принтеров локальной сети). Почитайте, что такое zeroconf -  более чем уверен, что это то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: броадкасты в ethernet не запрещены :)

Comment: @KoVadim, я вас понял. Но в данном случае лучше не использовать сторонние решения, а работать со стандартным TCP/IP, поскольку ведомые устройства - микроконтроллеры. Кроме того, я уточнил: использование широковещательного ip-адреса разрешено, если пакет отправляется в ту же сеть, в которой находится отправитель. При этом широковещательный ip-пакет с помощью ARP инкапсулируется в широковещательный ethernet-кадр. Запрещено лишь пересылать широковещательные пакеты в другие сети. Поэтому я выбрал правильным ответ @mantigatos.

Comment: Подробнее о запрете и атаке читайте:
http://www.warning.dp.ua/comp13.htm
http://rfc2.ru/2644.rfc/print
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack